# API ou framework que para busca por remédios em diferentes farmácias

Tags: objective-c

Preciso de alguma API ou framework que possa fazer uma busca por remédios em várias farmácias online brasileiras. Isso existe?

Comment: Eu acredito que não exista um serviço, ou biblioteca, que rastreie exclusivamente farmácias online. O mais provável é que você tenha que escrever o seu próprio *crawler* (que foi o que o Buscapé fez, provavelmente). Do jeito que está agora, sua pergunta é bem difícil de responder... Tente explicar melhor seu problema, e quais são seus requisitos ou opções existentes.

Comment: Editei a pergunta supondo que você precisa de um serviço brasileiro (se não for, por favor me corrija).

Comment: consegui atraves do PARSE com a ajuda de alguns colegas... mas muito obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Acho que isso realmente não existe. Eu também iria para a solução do crawler. Se partir nessa estratégia, existe um projeto da Apache que pode ajudar: http://nutch.apache.org/

Comment: Ricardo, você poderia postar como resposta a solução que usou? Não precisa ser o código todo do seu parser, o principal seria explicar os princípios usados para resolver o problema. Aqui no site, as perguntas e respostas são pensadas para ajudar mais gente além de quem respondeu, então ter esse conteúdo seria legal. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *site = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://....", termo]];
NSData *siteHTML = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:site];
TFHpple *siteParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:siteHTML];
```

Atraves de uma classe TFHpple foi possivel fazer o parse do site ;)

Vejam esse tutorial muito bom para mais informações:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios